# Installing Cocoapods on an M3 Mac with Sonoma fails with no error message

Tags: ruby, macos, cocoapods

I got a new MacBook Pro for work that is running Sonoma 14.2.1 on an M3. I'm trying to install Cocoapods but it seems to fail even though it "succeeds". Below is what I get when I run it - all seems well.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.13.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.13.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.13.0
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

When I try to look for it with `gem list` I do see it listed:

```
cocoapods (1.13.0)
cocoapods-core (1.14.3, 1.13.0)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.5)
cocoapods-downloader (2.1, 1.6.3)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
cocoapods-search (1.0.1)
cocoapods-trunk (1.6.0)
cocoapods-try (1.2.0)
```

But when I try to run it, I get:

```
 % pod                               
zsh: command not found: pod
```

Clearly I'm missing a step somewhere, but *what? *How do I get more information so I can figure out what may be amiss? I've tried this both in Rosetta and outside of it.

I installed ruby 3.0 - when I tried it using gem it failed with a make error:

```
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
+__rvm_make:0> return 2
```

but when I did it with brew it was fine.

Could this be a path issue? On my older Mac running Ventura on an M1 Cocoapods is under ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin/pod . Could it be putting it somewhere else since the installation wasn't in Rosetta at first?

Comment: I ended up using an answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61867107/zsh-command-not-found-pod-macos-catalina-10-15 that said to install it with brew and reboot and that did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an answer from here: [zsh: command not found: pod - macOS Catalina 10.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61867107/zsh-command-not-found-pod-macos-catalina-10-15)

But to summarize - uninstall every single cocoapods gem, use brew, and then reboot. That did it.

Answer (score 0):

`zsh: command not found: pod` means that `pod` is none of the following:

- a built-in shell command
- an alias defined in your shell config
- an executable in your `PATH`

`pod` definitely isn't gonna be the first one, so your options are to make an alias pointing at the `pod` executable or add that executable's directory to your `PATH`.

If you run `gem environment` you'll see something like `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0`. Look for it in there:

```
find /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ -name pod
```

Then define an alias or update your path:

```
alias pod=/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/whatever/it/ended/up/being/pod
# or
export PATH="/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/whatever/it/ended/up/being:$PATH"
```

But a much better way is to install Ruby via [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv). Then you'll get a much newer version of Ruby which you can customize per-project, including setting up separate gems.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up using brew. Please see my answer above.